# Token has expired

Tags: servicestack, jwt

```
Token has expired
  at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProviderReader.AssertJwtPayloadIsValid(JsonObject jwtPayload)
  at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProviderReader.CreateSessionFromPayload(IRequest req, JsonObject jwtPayload)
  at ServiceStack.Auth.JwtAuthProviderReader.PreAuthenticate(IRequest req, IResponse res)
  at ServiceStack.EnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 values, Action`1 action)
  at ServiceStack.AuthenticateAttribute.Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto)
  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.ApplyRequestFiltersSingle(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto)
  at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.ApplyRequestFilters(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto)
  at ServiceStack.Host.Handlers.GenericHandler.ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest httpReq, IResponse httpRes, String operationName)
```

this exeptions happens frequently.

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
   new IAuthProvider[]
     {
       new CredentialsAuthProvider(),
       new JwtAuthProvider(AppSettings)
         {
           AuthKeyBase64 = Configuration.GetValue("AuthKeyBase64"),
           RequireSecureConnection = false,
           PersistSession = false
         }
     }
));
```

Is that the way it should be or I just use it wrong way?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exception indicates the JWT token has expired, when that happens the client needs to re-authenticate to get a new one or [use its refresh token](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#refresh-tokens).

The [JWT docs contains a lot of detail on JWT expiration](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#lifetimes-of-tokens) including the config to control how long JWTs are valid for:

```
new JwtAuthProvider {
    ExpireTokensIn        = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),  // JWT Token Expiry
    ExpireRefreshTokensIn = TimeSpan.FromDays(365), // Refresh Token Expiry
}
```